# Search with Single Character using Regular expression ( lucene syntax) in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: c#, azure, lucene, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Cognitive Search with QueryType = SearchQueryType.Full with help of Regular expression search ( lucene syntax). I am using below regular expression

```
/.* {word} .*/
```

It is working fine with numeric values and words. But it is not working for Single Alphabet characters.

Example:

for searching "1 A September"

`/.*1.*/` -- *Working*
`/.*S.*/` -- *Working*
`/.*A.*/` -- *Not Working*

I am following the this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_regex

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Is the searchable field that contains this text configured with a language-specific analyzer, such as the en.lucene (English) analyzer? I wonder if you're not seeing results because "A" is a stop word and dropped during indexing.

Comment: Yes,I am using en.microsoft analyzer for this searchable field

Comment: Got it. In that case your options are to either switch to an analyzer that doesn't drop stop words (e.g. standard), or use a custom analyzer that preserves other properties of language-specific analyzers while keeping stop words. More details on custom analyzers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers